# Is there anyway to remove Gcaptcha response code in the email from a form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, recaptcha

Not sure how i'd approach this one. Upon submitting a contact form via AJAX, the re-catptcha code gets sent with the submission. However the code is really long and it's breaking the email layout. Is there any way to not include this in the submission? "G-Captcha Response" I am using web3forms for the form handling.

HTML

```
     <form action="https://api.web3forms.com/submit" method="POST" id="form">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="0add945e-609f-4a2b-b11d-f5fa14c8ad9a" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://web3forms.com/success" />
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;" />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Your name..." required />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Your email..." required />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                         <input name="subject" id="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your subject..." required>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea name="comments" id="message" rows="4" class="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Your message..." required /></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row mt-3">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                                <div
                                                    class="g-recaptcha"
                                                    data-sitekey="mysitekey"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="captcha-error"></div>
                                            <p id="result"></p>
                                              <button type="submit" class="submitBnt btn btn-custom">
                                        Send Message
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

JS

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const captchaError = document.getElementById("captcha-error")

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  e.preventDefault();
  var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
   if (response.length == 0) {
        alert("error with recaptcha")
         } else {
  var object = {};
  formData.forEach((value, key) => {
    object[key] = value;
  });
  var json = JSON.stringify(object);
  result.innerHTML = "Please wait...";
  captchaError.textContent = ""; 
   //reCaptch verified
  fetch("https://api.web3forms.com/submit", {
    
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    body: json
  })
    .then(async (response) => {
      let json = await response.json();
      if (response.status == 200) {
        result.innerHTML = json.message;
        result.classList.remove("text-gray-500");
        result.classList.add("text-green-500");
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        result.innerHTML = json.message;
        result.classList.remove("text-gray-500");
        result.classList.add("text-red-500");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      result.innerHTML = "Something went wrong!";
    })
    .then(function () {
      form.reset();
      setTimeout(() => {
        result.style.display = "none";
      }, 5000);
      grecaptcha.reset();
    });
    }
});
```